# opendmarc: hostnamefqdn() shows only short name / helo command rejected fqdn

Tags: perl, hostname

I have problem with opendmarc. This software uses perl function to send report mails. So in the source code  I see that /etc/opendmarc_reports uses also function hostnamefqdn() to pass it to helo command smtp. Then I see in postfix logs this message: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname.

My config:
/etc/hosts

127.0.1.1 mail.local mail

/etc/hostname

mail

```
$ hostname -f
mail.local
$ perl -e 'use Net::Domain qw(hostfqdn); print hostfqdn()."\n";'
mail
```

Why perl function hostnamefqdn() in this case return only short name domain instead fqdn ?
Of course when I change hostname to mail.local then everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Most code which tries to determine the host's FQDN does so by looking at the "canonical name" field that is returned by gethostbyname() or getaddrinfo() functions.

When the lookup is handled by /etc/hosts, the **first** name in each line is the "canonical" name of that entry, the rest are "alias" names. Your entry should look like:

```
127.0.1.1 mail.local mail
```

Comment: Of course I have set up in the same way as you show. Only my mistake when I was rewriting from my server. So on my another servers it works good. Only in one case I have problem with hostnamefqdn() and all the time it return non fqdn hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Net::Domain looks for the domain in several places:

1. Net::Config
2. /etc/resolv.conf - `search` and `domain` options
3. NIS (through the `domainname` command)
4. LOCALDOMAIN and DOMAIN environment variables
5. /etc/hosts, DNS (through `gethostbyname`)

According to comments in its code, this module aims to avoid DNS requests if possible.